# bash hardlinking not working

Tags: linux, bash, hardlink

I want to hardlink a dir to a different dir but this script doesn't work. It hardlinks to all the directories for some strange reason. so "tv show dir" gets hardlinked into 'moviesdestpath', 'tvdestdestpath' and 'miscdestpath'

any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
tvdestpath="/rpn-san/downloads/complete/torrents/tvshows-ready/$2"
moviedestpath="/rpn-san/downloads/complete/torrents/movies-ready/$2"
miscdestpath="/rpn-san/downloads/complete/torrents/misc-ready/$2"
torrentid="$1"
torrentname="$2"
torrentpath="$3"
torrentdir="$torrentpath/$torrentname"

#hardlink to "tvshows-ready"
cp -al "$torrentdir" "$tvdestpath/"
sleep 5
cp -al "$torrentdir" "$moviesdestpath/"
sleep 5
cp -al "$torrentdir" "$miscdestpath/"
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I am not familiar with the `-l` option to `cp`. What version of linux are you using?

Comment: Linux doesn't allow hard links to directories.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Beta GNU cp, `-l Make hard links instead of copies of non-directories.`

Comment: @123: News to me; thank you.

Answer (score -1):

All good figured it out, I'm an idiot. I'm literally copying to all directories when i shouldn't be.

```
#!/bin/bash
tvdestpath="/rpn-san/downloads/complete/torrents/tvshows-ready/$2"
moviedestpath="/rpn-san/downloads/complete/torrents/movies-ready/$2"
miscdestpath="/rpn-san/downloads/complete/torrents/misc-ready/$2"
torrentid="$1"
torrentname="$2"
torrentpath="$3"
torrentdir="$torrentpath/$torrentname"

#hardlink to "tvshows-ready"
if [ "$torrentpath" == "/rpn-san/downloads/complete/torrents/tvshows" ]; then
cp -al "$torrentdir" "$tvdestpath/"
fi

sleep 5
#hardlink to "movies-ready"
if [ "$torrentpath" == "/rpn-san/downloads/complete/torrents/movies" ]; then
cp -al "$torrentdir" "$moviedestpath/"
fi

sleep 5
#hardlink to "misc-ready"
if [ "$torrentpath" == "/rpn-san/downloads/complete/torrents/misc" ]; then
cp -al "$torrentdir" "$miscdestpath/"
fi
```